# Example three.js glTF loader not rendering 3D model

Tags: three.js, gltf

When I download the [three.js-master](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip) folder on [threejs.org](https://threejs.org), and open up the glTF loader example (file name `webgl_loader_gltf.html`), my browser does not render the 3D model.

It should show the 3D helmet like on the [web version](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html), but all I see is a black screen. I suspect the actual model is there, but the lighting or mesh isn't set up correctly?

What I see:

[image]

What I should see:

[image]

I checked the console window in Safari Developer Mode, and discovered these two errors that might be the cause. Most notable is `cannot load due to access control checks`:

[image]

I have tried it using Google Chrome but same issue. I made sure the actual 3D model is in the folder (three.js-master > examples > models > gltf > DamagedHelmet).

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - glTF loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a {
                color: #75ddc1;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - GLTFLoader<br />
        Battle Damaged Sci-fi Helmet by
        <a href="https://sketchfab.com/theblueturtle_" target="_blank" rel="noopener">theblueturtle_</a><br />
        <a href="https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=pedestrian_overpass" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Pedestrian Overpass</a> by <a href="https://hdrihaven.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">HDRI Haven</a>
    </div>

    <script src="../build/three.js"></script>

    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="js/loaders/EquirectangularToCubeGenerator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/RGBELoader.js"></script>

    <script src="js/pmrem/PMREMGenerator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pmrem/PMREMCubeUVPacker.js"></script>

    <script src="js/WebGL.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false ) {
            document.body.appendChild( WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage() );
        }
        var container, stats, controls;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20 );
            camera.position.set( - 1.8, 0.9, 2.7 );
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.target.set( 0, - 0.2, - 0.2 );
            controls.update();
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var loader = new THREE.RGBELoader().setPath( 'textures/equirectangular/' );
            loader.load( 'pedestrian_overpass_2k.hdr', function ( texture ) {
                texture.encoding = THREE.RGBEEncoding;
                texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
                texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
                texture.flipY = true;
                var cubeGenerator = new THREE.EquirectangularToCubeGenerator( texture, { resolution: 1024 } );
                cubeGenerator.update( renderer );
                var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( cubeGenerator.renderTarget.texture );
                pmremGenerator.update( renderer );
                var pmremCubeUVPacker = new THREE.PMREMCubeUVPacker( pmremGenerator.cubeLods );
                pmremCubeUVPacker.update( renderer );
                var envMap = pmremCubeUVPacker.CubeUVRenderTarget.texture;
                // model
                var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/gltf/DamagedHelmet/glTF/' );
                loader.load( 'DamagedHelmet.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
                    gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child.isMesh ) {
                            child.material.envMap = envMap;
                        }
                    } );
                    scene.add( gltf.scene );
                } );
                pmremGenerator.dispose();
                pmremCubeUVPacker.dispose();
                scene.background = cubeGenerator.renderTarget;
            } );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            // stats
            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        //
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            stats.update();
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can't simply open an `.html` file stored in your hard drive, and have it gather assets also stored in your hard drive. This would be a huge security vulnerability for malicious people to read all the documents you have stored there, so the browser protects you from that. You need to set up a local server, as explained in the answer below, which delivers the files in the safer `http` protocol without granting access to your `C:/` drive.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are just opening the file, rather than serving the file via a local server.
It is outlined on the three.js docs page titled [How to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally).

> Content loaded from external files
>   If you load models or textures from
>   external files, due to browsers' same origin policy security
>   restrictions, loading from a file system will fail with a security
>   exception.
>
> There are two ways to solve this:
>
> Change security for local files in a browser.
>   This allows you to
>   access your page as:
>   file:///yourFile.html
>
> Run files from a local web server.
>   This allows you to access your page as:
>   http://localhost/yourFile.html

Answer (score 1):

Per @2pha solution, I opened Terminal on Mac and entered the following:

```
sudo npm install http-server -g
```

If you don't enter `sudo` it might not work due to administrative privileges. After letting it run, I entered:

```
http-server . -p 8000
```

You should see an output like this:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://192.168.0.5:8000
  http://127.0.0.1:8000
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Next, open up a browser and enter this address: `http://localhost:8000`. Navigate to the `.html` file (in my case `webgl_loader_gltf.html`) and open it up. It should work!

Comment: probably need to install node.js first